Django Best practices: migration & contenarization
I am working on a Django API and I'd like to add a bit of CI/CD to it.
It dockerize my app with
FROM python:3.12

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=vocab_dictionnary.settings

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

I then add a docker-compose.yml
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER="
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD="
      - "POSTGRES_DB="
    ports:
      - 5438:5432
    healthcheck: 
      test: pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres} -d ${POSTGRES_DB:-${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}}
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120
      start_period: 30s
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"

volumes:
  postgres_data:

The end of my main.yml file for github actions looks like this
- name: Run Database Migrations
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.SERVER_HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.SERVER_USERNAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.SERVER_PASSWORD }}
    script: |
      cd /${{ secrets.SERVER_USERNAME }}/api/vocab_dictionnary/
      docker compose exec web python manage.py migrate

Finally, to simplify my local dev workflow, I added this in a Makefile:
restart:
    docker compose down
    docker compose build
    docker compose up -d
    docker compose run web python3 manage.py makemigrations
    docker compose run web python3 manage.py migrate

My first problem is that my migrations doen't apply in local. I stay with this message where the makemigrations seems to be recognized but not applied with migrate
docker compose run web python3 manage.py makemigrations
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container vocab_dictionnary-db-1  Running                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
Migrations for 'dictionnary':
  dictionnary/migrations/0002_languages_is_valid.py
    - Add field is_valid to languages
docker compose run web python3 manage.py migrate
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container vocab_dictionnary-db-1  Running                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, dictionnary, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

If I understood well this page, I can replace my action by an auto migration in my docker-compose or with an entrypoint in my Dockerfile, but is there any best practice ? I can't find anything recommanded by Django itself about migrations in the context of contenarization with docker compose

See this answer on the duplicate target. Your problem is that you're running makemigrations on a container and then the container stops and all file changes are lost. You need to reconsider your workflow with the migrations (Read the guidance in that answer). You could try mounting your code as a volume, you seem to partly be doing that but you aren't actually running the command in the mounted volume.

I'm still stuck with this problem..
The other stack overflow doesn't really answer my problem. With this post, I'd like to gather informations about how to contenarize a Django application because the workflow with migrations is not clear..
Now my local migrations are good but it's still impossible for me to apply new migrations on my server.
